# bash command in gtk

Tags: python, bash, gtk

I am using File Selection in Gtk2. I want use Bash Command(stat "some directory") in python.
here in this code,file directory is saved in "text" variable..
but it doesn't working.I don't want use python-built stat() method.

```css
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygtk
import gtk
import os

class fileselection:
  def file_ok_sel(self,w):

    print("%s " % self.filew.get_filename())
    text=self.filew.get_filename()
    print(text)
    os.system("stat os.listdir("text")")
    #print(os.stat(text))
    #os.system("stat os.dir(text)")
    
    
  def destroy(self,widget):
    gtk.main_quit()
    
  def __init__(self):
    self.filew=gtk.FileSelection("File selection")
    self.filew.connect("destroy",self.destroy)
    self.filew.ok_button.connect("clicked",self.file_ok_sel)
    self.filew.cancel_button.connect("clicked",lambda w:self.filew.destroy())
    self.filew.set_filename("penguin.png")
    self.filew.show()
def main():
  gtk.main()
  return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
  fileselection()
  main()
```

Comment: You need to concatenate strings using `+`, not by juxtaposition: `"stat os.listdir("text")"` does not work; `"stat os.listdir(" + text + ")"` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.system('stat' + ' '.join(os.listdir(text)))
```

You should also consider using `subprocess` module instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess